# $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n + 100}$ eventually decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that the sequence $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n + 100}$ is eventually decreasing (so that I can use alternating series test with $\sum (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n + 100}$).

When I try to prove that a sequence is decreasing $a_n \geq a_{n + 1}$, I try either $a_n - a_{n +1} \geq 0$ or either $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq 1$. I have tried the former, but with the square roots it gets messy. In the latter I arrive to:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \sqrt{\frac{n + 1}{n}} \left( \frac{n + 100}{n + 100 + 1} \right)$$

It's clear that the limit of this expression is 1. But I don't know how to find a $N$, such that for $n \geq N$ we have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq 1$.

Comment: Show that the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}/(x+100)$ is eventually decreasing.

Comment: @HansEngler Hadn't thought about it, I'm studying sequences and series for the moment. That seems easier. Would the proof using sequences be very complicated?

Comment: If you prove using a function that it's true beginning with some real number $x_0$, it will be true a fortiori for $n > \lceil x_0 \rceil$

Comment: Let $c=100$. To prove $\sqrt{n}+c/\sqrt{n}$ is eventually increasing, note $n\mapsto n+1$ increases it by $(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(1-c/\sqrt{n(n+1)})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{\frac{n+1}n}\left(\frac{n+100}{n+100+1} \right)\le1&\iff(n+100)^2(n+1)\le(n+101)^2n\\
&\iff(n+100)^2\le\left((n+101)^2-(n+100)^2\right)n\\
&\iff n^2+200n+100^2\le2n^2+201n\\
&\iff100^2\le n(n+1)\\
&\iff n\ge100.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to prove $$\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^2\le 1$$for $n\ge N$. You get$$\frac{(n+1)(n+100)^2}{n(n+101)^2}=\frac{(n+1)(n^2+200n+10000)}{n(n^2+202n+10201)}\\=\frac{n^3+201n^2+10200n+10000}{n^3+202n^2+10201n}$$
Now all you need is $$202n^2+10201n\ge 201n^2+10200n+10000\\n^2+n-10000\ge 0$$
Can you take it from here?